# Finding adjoint of an operator from $\mathbb{C}^n$ to $H$

Tags: functional-analysis

> Suppose we have vectors $h_1,\ldots,h_n \in H$, where $H$ is a Hilbert space. Define $B : \mathbb{C}^n \to H$ by $$B(z_1,\ldots,z_n)=\sum_{j=1}^n z_j h_j.$$ Calculate $B^* : H \to \mathbb{C}^n$.

My trouble is setting up the inner product that is associated with Hilbert spaces. Should I first write $\langle Bz, h \rangle$ (for $z =(z_1,\ldots,z_n) \in \mathbb{C}^n$ and $h \in H$) and work with this expression to find an expression for $\langle z,B^* h \rangle$?

Comment: yes, exactly. you might want to explain why $B^*$ is continuous. but that's all trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any $z\in\mathbb C^n$ and $h\in H$ we have 
$$  \langle Bz, h \rangle = \sum_{j=1}^n z_j \langle h_j, h \rangle = z^H (\langle h_j, h \rangle )_{1\le j\le n}. $$
Thus, it follows
$$ B^*(h) = \begin{bmatrix} \langle h_1, h \rangle \\ \vdots \\ \langle h_n, h \rangle \end{bmatrix}, $$
which is linear and continuous in $h$, as the inner product is bilinear and continuous.

Comment: For your last line, you mean "linear and continuous in $H$", right?

Comment: @lesguimauves: I meant the expression for $B^*(h)$ in linear and continuous in the variable $h$, that is $B^*$ is a linear and continuous mapping from $H$ into $\mathbb C^n$.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach sounds like it should work. This should get you started: using the standard basis for $\mathbb{C}^n$ and linearity of the inner product on $H$, we note that
$$
\langle Bz,h\rangle = \langle z,B^*h\rangle = \sum_{j=1}^n z_j\langle e_j,B^*h\rangle.
$$
Use your expression for $Bz$ to determine the $\langle e_j,B^*h\rangle$. (Alter things as you need to for a conjugate linear inner product.)

Note that this doesn't require you to know the definition of the inner product on $H$ beforehand; rather, this problem is asking you to *deduce* the value of the inner product in a few specific cases.

Comment: @lesguimauves here $e_1,\dotsc,e_n$ is the basis for $\mathbb C^n$, not for $H$.

Comment: @lesguimauves As user251257 said. The notation may be confusing you; I should probably have specified what space each inner product takes place in.